# How to detect which button is clicked and if two are clicked then call the method?

Tags: asp.net

```
 protected void Button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (TextBox2.Text == "P" && TextBox3.Text == "E" && TextBox4.Text == "N")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You Earn 100 Coins");


           bool Button8_Click = true;
             bool Btn = true;
             if (Btn == true && Button8_Click == true)
             {
                 // Button11_Click1(sender, e);
                 TextBox5.Text = sc();
                 Session["s"] = TextBox5.Text.ToString();
             }
             else if (Btn == false && Button8_Click == true)
             {
                 TextBox5.Text = sr();
                 Session["s"] = TextBox5.Text.ToString();
             }

            Session["s"] = TextBox5.Text.ToString();
            Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx");
        }

        }
```

What I want is if `btn11` and `btn8` both are clicked then call `sc` method if only one `btn8` is clicked call `sr` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it simultaneously due to events aren't asynchronous. You have to store the first click on Button8 in variable and the second click on Button11 will check the variable to call the right method.

You are in WEB process so you can't say to HTTP request to manage two event in only one request ;-).

If you want to do that you can do it with AJAX request. The principle is that you call the same WebMethod with a lock inside allows you to assign a variable for first button and after that on the second call you can't check the value of variable and call the right method.

Let's me illustrate to you a quickly sample of what you must have

```
public static readonly object Lock = new object();

public static bool isBtn8Clicked = false;

[WebMethod]
public void CallMeBaby(string btnName){
    lock (TypeOfMyPage.obj) {
        isBtn8Clicked = true;
    }

    //Your business code
}
```

Comment: Yes that's my first idea but after more reflection, I saw that is not possible ^^. In fact, you can't do it in server side due to HTTP request lifecycle. Even in AJAX request, the method will treat just one by one request and you don't know which request will be treated first ...